# I would like others to explain this piece of code to me

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the code below that should do bring to me a list of users. I was testing the "Take" function to do a pagination but it just doesn't work.

```
using (MyContainer myContainer = new MyContainer())
{
    // Works
    var user = myContainer.User.Where(u => u.Name == Name).ToList();
    // The "Name" comes from User.Name
    // myContainer is generated by my edmx he inherits the ObjectContext in the design generated by edmx as it shows below
    //// public partial class MyContainer : ObjectContext

    // Does not work
    var foo = (from t in myContainer.User
               select t.Name).Take(10);

    return user;
}
```

Why the being so similar to the first doesn't work.

Throw exception *"Cannot convert Lambda expression to type 'string'  because it is not a delegate type"*

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're having? It's unclear.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is really not enough... Did you interpret the error message yet?

Comment: What is the definition of the `Name` property? Does it has some computation?

Comment: it's not "Does not work" I'm just trying to understand the code. Like it says on [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) "However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK."

Comment: @IlyaIvanov As I stated in a comment on the code. `// The "Name" comes from User.Name` saying it, you can see that `User` is a table that was generated by my edmx

Comment: Instead of quoting the rules you could try to explain "doesn't work".

Comment: The down- and close-votes *are* appropriate because you need to specifically ask what you want explained or what doesn't work.

Comment: @usr take a look, I appreciate if you could edit my question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't expect the 2 forms to work identically, as they're different. you can express the 2nd in function chain like this:

```
var foo = myContainer.User.Select(u => u.Name).Take(10);
```

which, as expected, doesn't work like the first form, as it returns an `IEnumerable<string>` when the first returns an `List<User>`

Comment: Now it makes senses. I just got lost of the track and didn't noticed that

Answer (score 2):

First expression returns a list of `User`s.

Second expression returns a list of `Name`s (name is probably a string).

You should probably do something like:

```
var user = myContainer.User.Where(u => u.Name == Name).Take(10).ToList();
```

As a sidenote, I believe that you need a little bit more for pagination, I guess using .Skip(*something*).Take(*something*)

Comment: Thanks. Going to test it. =) Looks very promising =)

Comment: I took [Stephane's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15069092/662581) as the right one because the explaining of the reason. But upvoted yours. Thanks for the sidenote. Really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try `myContainer.User.Take(10).ToList()` to get a list of first 10 users or `myContainer.User.Take(10).Select(iter => iter.Name).ToList()` to get the list of first 10 names.

Comment: Thanks! that's really a good advice.